# MacBook a1502 freezing keyboard

Tags: keyboard

MacBook keyboard stops working shortly after reboot, but there's a catch! Like, lots of them:

1. It only stops working when using built-in keyboard, but...
2. Physically, the built-in keyboard is fine! (see p.4 for explanation)
3. When the issue gets manifested even external keyboard doesn't work. But external keyboard doesn't trigger it on its own
4. All keyboard events are read properly all the time. I've booted into Linux live CD, launched `xev` utility and I can see that all keyboard codes are read properly even when the issue is manifested.
5. Magically, `ctrl+q` unfreezes keyboard for 1 character, so I can type something, but this is bothersome

I tried NVRAM reset couple of times but it didn't help.
Anything else you may suggest? Any idea why keys are read physically, but it's as if macbook blocks the signal elsewhere?

Comment: you have a app that is taking control of the keyboard

Comment: In that case it wouldn't be reproducible in Linux Live CD as this is clean pre-configured environment, but it does. So the question is where that app might even be installed? I suspect EFI firmware needs a patch